# Passport validity requirements for transit stop-overs in Doha and Dubai

Tags: passports, dubai, stopovers, doha

I'm flying with Qatar airways in June from Australia to the UK, with a stopover in Doha. On the way home I'll be travelling from Germany to Australia with Qantas, stopping in Dubai.

On the way there I'll have about 4 months validity on my passport, and then less than 3 months on the way home. This is fine for the countries I'm actually traveling within, but what about transit countries? I'm only in Doha for 1 hour and I'm not leaving the airport, similar for Dubai; does it matter that I'll have less than the 6 months required to enter their country?

Can someone please explain the rules and regulations surrounding this sort of situation.

Answer (score 4):

There will be absolutely no issue, as none of the transit countries have airside transit visa requirements; so you are never actually "entering the country".

In other words - as long as your passport allows you entry into your destination country (either by your citizenship or because it has a visa stamped) you will be issued a boarding pass on the start of your journey.

That's all you need throughout the journey.

Relax, and enjoy your trip!

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I'll be able to relax until I actually arrive in the UK, but at least now I know I'm worrying for no reason.